# What does VK stand for in Java's KeyEvent class?

Tags: java, keyevent

I would like to know, what does VK stand for in java?

Here is an instance code in order to give you a brief idea where it is used:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ if (e.getKeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {...}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a shorthand for "Virtual Key":

> [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html):
>
> **Virtual key** codes are used to report which keyboard key has been pressed, rather than a character generated by the combination of one or more keystrokes (such as "A", which comes from shift and "a").